# Output to amd module without webpackBootstrap

Tags: webpack

I'm converting amd modules to ES6/Typescript modules one by one. I have to integrate with an existing requirejs build until every amd module is converted. The way I've done this so far is to create a webpack config with its own entry point for each amd module. Maybe there's a better way to do this but I haven't discovered it so far. The reason I'm doing many individual webpack configs--one for each amd module--is because of the new libraryExport property in webpack@3. Without that property, when the existing require build system imports one of the ES6 compiled to amd modules, it needs to be the actual thing being exported from that module that is imported. Not the module object itself.

So anyway, this works--but please let me know if there's a better way to do this :)

My real question is, being that I am compiling ES6 module -> amd module one to one, and there are no interdependencies, can I get the webpackBootstrap boilerplate code removed from each amd module that I'm exporting?